# Getting underflow error when using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I am creating an app that sends an image to the server, the server will run the image through a neural network, and output the results.
This is the neural network class I am using:

```
 class Network(object):

def __init__(self, sizes):
    self.num_layer = len(sizes)
    self.sizes = sizes
    self.biases = [np.random.randn(y,1) for y in sizes [1:]]
    self.weights = [np.random.randn(y,x) for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]

def feedforward(self, a):
    for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
        a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a) + b)
    return a 

def SGD(self, training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta, test_data = None):

    list_training_data = list(training_data)
    if test_data: 
        list_test_Data = list(test_data)
        n_test = len(list_test_Data)
    n = len(list_training_data)
    for j in range(epochs):
        random.shuffle(list_training_data)
        mini_batches = [list_training_data[k:k+mini_batch_size]for k in range(0,n,mini_batch_size)]
        for mini_batch in mini_batches:
            self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch,eta)
        if test_data:
            evulate = self.evaluate(list_test_Data);
            print("Epoch{0}:{1}/{2}" .format( j, evulate, n_test))
        else:
            print("Epoch {0} complete". format(j))

def backdrop(self, x, y):
    nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
    nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
    activation = x
    activations = [x]
    zs = []
    for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
        z = np.dot(w, activation) + b
        zs.append(z)
        activation = sigmoid(z)
        activations.append(activation)
    delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * \
        sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])
    nabla_b[-1] = delta
    nabla_w[-1] = np.dot(delta, activations[-1-1].transpose())
    return (nabla_b, nabla_w)

def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta):
    nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
    nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
    for x, y in mini_batch:
        delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backdrop(x, y)
        nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
        nabla_w = [nw+dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]
    self.weights = [w-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nw
                    for w ,nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
    self.biases = [b - (eta/len(mini_batch))*nb
                    for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]

def evaluate(self, test_data):
    test_results = [(np.argmax(self.feedforward(x)), y)for (x, y) in test_data]
    final = sum(int(x==y)for (x,y) in test_results)
    return final

def cost_derivative(self, output_activatoins, y):
    return (output_activatoins - y)

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-z))

def sigmoid_prime(z):
    return sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))
```

I am getting this error from numpy and I am not sure how I would resolve this.

```
 C:/Users/name/Desktop/server.py:91: RuntimeWarning: underflow encountered in exp
 np.getter()
 ERROR:__main__:Exception on / [POST]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\name\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.7\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
 response = self.full_dispatch_request()
 File "C:\Users\name\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.7\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
 response = self.make_response(rv)
 File "C:\Users\name\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.7\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1577, in make_response
rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
 File "C:\Users\name\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.7\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 847, in force_type
 response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
 File "C:\Users\name\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.7\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py", line 871, in run_wsgi_app
app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable
```

This is the line where the error occurs:

```
def sigmoid(z):
    np.seterr(over='ignore')
    return 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-z))
```

The strange thing is when I run the neural network I get the correct result. When I run it through a server I get `TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable`

Comment: I'd say the TypeError looks like a much bigger concern. The underflow is just a warning, which can be easily disabled with the `np.seterr` function you're already using.

Comment: I can't figure out why I am getting that error either. It must be under the same function.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket after `np.exp(-z)`

Comment: No that was a typing error when I was posting it. Its not like that on my code.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place - the underflow warning seems to be unrelated to the `TypeError` that is crashing your program.

Comment: I made changes to the question hope that helps

Comment: please post with the appropriate tags; this is not a flask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there was nothing wrong with the code. The reason I got this error msg is because the server is not sending the result in type JSON. To fix this error I imported jsonify from Flask, and wrote `return jsonify(results = answer)`

Answer (score 2):

### Prevent overflow

Use this Sigmoid implementation to prevent overflow and underflow in the sigmoid.

```
def sigmoid_function( signal, derivative=False ):
    # Prevent overflow.
    signal = np.clip( signal, -500, 500 )

    # Calculate activation signal
    signal = 1.0 / (1 + np.exp( -signal ))

    if derivative:
        # Return the partial derivation of the activation function
        return np.multiply(signal, 1-signal)
    else:
        # Return the activation signal
        return signal
#end activation function
```

#### Type error:

It is impossible for us to help you with this error, since you haven't posted the full code. However, that error often occur when you've made a typo and try to call a numeric variable as a function. The last issue is a better fit with [Code Review StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).